# Http polling until request is fulfilled with Rx

Tags: .net, rest, observablecollection, system.reactive, polling

I am requesting a resource over http from a restful api. The resource takes time to reach a 'complete' status and the responding http status code reflects the completeness of the resource.

The calling client is a user waiting to consume the resource who does not want to wait indefinitely. Therefore the api is polled up to a maximum number of attempts to get a 'complete' resource. Should the api return a status indicating the resource is complete, the resource is then returned up the stack for consumption. If the api does not return a status indicating the resource is complete within the maximum number of attempts then the client should stop polling and just return some kind of failure status.

In order to achieve this at the moment I am using `Thread.Sleep(500)` to block the thread that is waiting for the result. Its causing me nightmares thinking how inefficient this is, so I am looking to improve the technique.

I have looked into `Rx` and trying in vain to bend the `Observable.Interval()` to my will but I am having trouble trying to observe on the calling thread. I would ideally like to know what my code should look like! Currently at:

```
 Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
           .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
           .Take(10)
           .Subscribe(i =>
               {
                  // check if resource is complete
               });
```

Comment: Can the server approximate how long the resource will take to complete? It might be helpful to return that as well as the status. Also, I'm no .net expert, but I don't see how what you're doing is significantly different from sleeping.

Comment: The api has no knowledge of how long the resource will take to complete. Sleeping is what I'm currently using to keep hold of the thread but I don't believe its the best way of doing so. Its screaming Async at me but I'm unsure how to go about it!

Comment: If you make a new thread, sleep and poll on that, and update your main application when the resource is ready, how is that not async?

Comment: That is async but it doesn't satisfy the code execution path. The resource needs to be returned to the calling thread...

Comment: Do you really need to worry about threading at all? Do you have access to the TPL? (Tasks and async/await)

Comment: Yep, all access to the TPL. Solution doesn't have to be Rx at all - just thought the `.Interval()` extension might be useful...

Comment: The Interval solution doesn't take into account the duration of the request, which could exceed the the interval. Instead, you'd need to use something that has a concatenating effect. this happens naturally with the TPL, but you'd need to use something like Retry/Repeat when using Rx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the TPL route in the end. I avoided the explicit Thread.Sleep by using Task.Delay, which is one less namespace to reference at least.

```
public class HttpRequestRetrierResponseContainer<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsCriteriaMet { get; set; }
    public int AttemptCount { get; set; }
}

public class HttpRequestRetrier
{
    private readonly IHttpClientWrapper _httpClientWrapper;

    public HttpRequestRetrier(IHttpClientWrapper httpClientWrapper)
    {
        _httpClientWrapper = httpClientWrapper;
    }

    public async Task<HttpRequestRetrierResponseContainer<T>> RepeatRequestUntilResponseMeetsCriteria<T>(Func<HttpRequestMessage> getMessage, Predicate<HttpResponseMessage> criteria, int maxAttempts)
    {
        return await Attempt<T>(getMessage, criteria, maxAttempts, 0);
    }

    private async Task<HttpRequestRetrierResponseContainer<T>> Attempt<T>(Func<HttpRequestMessage> getMessage, Predicate<HttpResponseMessage> criteria, int maxAttempts, int attemptCount)
    {
        if (attemptCount < maxAttempts)
        {
            var response = await _httpClientWrapper.SendMessageAsync(getMessage);

            if (criteria(response))
            {
                var value = await response.Extensions().ReadAsAsync<T>();
                return new HttpRequestRetrierResponseContainer<T> { IsCriteriaMet = true, AttemptCount = attemptCount, Value = value };
            }

            Task.Delay(500).Wait();

            return await Attempt<T>(getMessage, criteria, maxAttempts, attemptCount + 1);
        }

        return new HttpRequestRetrierResponseContainer<T> { IsCriteriaMet = false };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Observable.FromAsync(token => restSharpClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, token))
    .SelectMany(response =>
        response.Data.HasCompleted
            ? Observable.Return(response)
            : Observable.ThrowException(new Exception("Resource not ready."))
                .DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        )
    .Retry(10);
```